# Why can't the ant colony algorithm of calculating the maximum point of the function converge to the maximum point

Tags: mathematical-optimization, algorithm

```
   P0 = 0.2;(*Transfer probability constant*)

antNumber = 300;

Rho = 0.9;(*Pheromone Volatilization Coefficient*)
ants = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], antNumber];
evaluatetau[{x_, 
    y_}] := -(x^4 + 3*y^4 - 0.2*Cos[3*π*x] - 0.4*Cos[4*π*y] + 
     0.6);
tau = Map[evaluatetau[#] &, ants];
select[ants_, tau_, lamuda_] := 
 Module[{sants = ants, taubest = Max[tau], p, lsindex, gsindex, 
   objvalue, sobjvalue, tindex}, sants = ants;
  taubest = Max[tau];
  p = Abs[taubest - tau]/taubest;
  lsindex = Flatten[Position[p, n_ /; n < P0], 1];
  gsindex = Flatten[Position[p, n_ /; n >= P0], 1];
  (*Local search*)r = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Length[lsindex], 2}];

  sants[[lsindex]] = sants[[lsindex]] + (2*r - 1)*lamuda;

  (*global search*)r = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Length[gsindex], 2}];

  sants[[gsindex]] = sants[[gsindex]] + 2 (r - 0.5);

  sants = {Max[-1, Min[1, #[[1]]]], Max[-1, Min[1, #[[2]]]]} & /@ 
    sants; objvalue = Map[evaluatetau[#] &, ants]; 
  sobjvalue = Map[evaluatetau[#] &, sants];
  tindex = Flatten@Position[Negative[sobjvalue - objvalue], True];
  sants[[tindex]] = ants[[tindex]];
  sants
  ]

For[t = 1, t <= 500, t++, ants = select[ants, tau, 1/t]; 
 tau = (1 - Rho)*tau + Map[evaluatetau[#] &, ants];]
Show[ListPointPlot3D[Map[Flatten, {#, evaluatetau[#]} & /@ ants], 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
 Plot3D[-(x^4 + 3*y^4 - 0.2*Cos[3*π*x] - 0.4*Cos[4*π*y] + 
     0.6), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]]
```

This is a code used by ant colony algorithm to calculate the maximum value point of function `-(x^4 + 3*y^4 - 0.2*Cos[3*π*x] - 0.4*Cos[4*π*y] + 0.6)`, but its results cannot converge to the maximum point as shown in the figure below:

[image]

How to modify it to make the last ant population almost all converge to the maximum point.

I think the community administrator should open a special post to introduce the genetic algorithm, ant colony algorithm and other algorithms written by MMA, which are often used in University. This will attract more college students to have an interest in MMA.

Code of Matlab version:

```matlab
    clear;
    clc;

    Ant     =   30;    
    Times   =  2000;     
    Rho     =   0.9;    
    P0      =   0.2;    
    xl = -1; xu = 1;    
    yl = -1; yu = 1;
    step = 0.05;

    ants = initant(Ant, xl, xu, yl, yu);  
    tau = calObjFun(ants);                  
    firstants = ants;

    for t = 1:Times
        ants = edgeselection(ants, P0, tau, 1/t, xl, xu, yl, yu);   
        tau = (1 - Rho) .* tau + calObjFun(ants);             
    end

    figure(1);
    plotobjfun(xl, xu, yl, yu, step);
    hold on;
    plot3(firstants(:,1), firstants(:,2), calObjFun(firstants), 'b*');
    hold on;
    plot3(ants(:,1), ants(:,2), calObjFun(ants), 'r*');
    hold off;
    function sants = edgeselection(ants, tau, P0, lamda, xl, xu, yl, yu)

    sants = ants;


    [taubest, ~] = max(tau);
    p = abs((taubest - tau) / taubest);


    lsindex = find(p < P0);
    gsindex = find(p >= P0);


    r = rand(length(lsindex), 2);
    sants(lsindex, :) = sants(lsindex, :) + (2 .* r - 1) .* lamda;


    r = rand(length(gsindex), 2);
    gedge = repmat([xu-xl, yu-yl], length(gsindex), 1);
    sants(gsindex,:) = sants(gsindex,:) + gedge .* (r - 0.5);

    sants(sants(:, 1) < xl, 1) = xl;
    sants(sants(:, 1) > xu, 1) = xu;
    sants(sants(:, 2) < yl, 2) = yl;
    sants(sants(:, 2) > yu, 2) = yu;

    objvalue = calObjFun(ants);
    sobjvalue = calObjFun(sants);
    tindex = find(sobjvalue < objvalue);
    sants(tindex, :) = ants(tindex, :);
    end
    function ants = initant(num, xl, xu, yl, yu)

    ants = rand(num, 2);
    ants(:,1) = xl + (xu - xl) .* ants(:,1);
    ants(:,2) = yl + (yu - yl) .* ants(:,2);
    end
    function objval = calObjFun(X)

    objval = -(X(:,1) .^ 4 + 3 .* X(:,2) .^ 4 - 0.2 .* cos(3*pi .* X(:,1)) ...
        - 0.4 .* cos(4*pi .* X(:,2)) + 0.6);
    end
    function plotobjfun(xl, xu, yl, yu, step)

    [x, y] = meshgrid(xl:step:xu, yl:step:yu);
    f = '-(x.^4 + 3*y.^4 - 0.2*cos(3*pi*x) - 0.4*cos(4*pi*y) + 0.6)';
    z = eval(f);
    mesh(x, y, z);
    end
```

Comment: This strikes me as more of a math/computer science question than a *Mathematica* one, because it seems like you're asking about how to fix the *algorithm*.

Comment: I think the community administrator should open a special post to introduce the genetic algorithm, ant colony algorithm and other algorithms written by MMA, which are often used in University.

Comment: You could write a self-answered question **if** you already have working code, but asking people to debug complicated code you already have is a stretch of others' kindness and time.

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes the suggestion by JM is a good one, if you think you have some attempts at these algorithms, open up a question & make an attempt at a self-answer. As it stands, however, your question is definitely one of general algorithms, as stated by march. Your suggestion is a great one, also, and it is important to note that we are all moderators/administrators on SE, and that is the beauty of the platform.

Comment: How are these fancy evolutional codes ever supposed to be better than running the most efficient local optimization algorithm (say, BFGS) with initial conditions randomly sampled all over the domain (or any coarse upper bound of the set of minimizers)? Really, there is no point in wanting _all_ ants to find the maximum; it suffices if _one_ ant finds it. All other online communication between the ants is just inefficient.

Comment: Btw.: This is how bees work: They spread ou randomly and if one bee finds a source of food, it returns to the hive and [_just tells the others_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waggle_dance) where to find it. _That's_ efficiency.

Comment: @J.M.isinlimbo I'm sorry to bother you with my question, but I've been looking for two days and I haven't found out where the error is. In the Matlab version of the code, all ants can finally converge to the location near {0,0}.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because MSE is not really intended as a free resource for debugging programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After careful investigation, we finally found the reason for the non convergence:

```
 P0 = 0.2;(*Transfer probability constant*)

    antNumber = 300;

    Rho = 0.9;(*Pheromone Volatilization Coefficient*)
    ants = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], antNumber];
    evaluatetau[{x_, 
        y_}] := -(x^4 + 3*y^4 - 0.2*Cos[3*Pi*x] - 0.4*Cos[4*Pi*y] + 
         0.6);
    tau = Map[evaluatetau[#] &, ants];
    select[ants_, tau_, lamuda_] := 
     Module[{sants = ants, taubest = Max[tau], p, lsindex, gsindex, 
       objvalue, sobjvalue, tindex}, sants = ants;
      taubest = Max[tau];
      p = Abs[(taubest - tau)/
        taubest](*The position of brackets in this place is different 
    from that of Matlab version,which needs to be modified*);
      lsindex = Flatten[Position[p, n_ /; n < P0], 1];
      gsindex = Flatten[Position[p, n_ /; n >= P0], 1];
      (*Local search*)r = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Length[lsindex], 2}];

      sants[[lsindex]] = sants[[lsindex]] + (2*r - 1)*lamuda;

      (*global search*)r = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Length[gsindex], 2}];

      sants[[gsindex]] = sants[[gsindex]] + 2 (r - 0.5);

      sants = {Max[-1, Min[1, #[[1]]]], Max[-1, Min[1, #[[2]]]]} & /@ 
        sants; objvalue = Map[evaluatetau[#] &, ants]; 
      sobjvalue = Map[evaluatetau[#] &, sants];
      tindex = Flatten@Position[Negative[sobjvalue - objvalue], True];
      sants[[tindex]] = ants[[tindex]];
      sants
      ]

    For[t = 1, t <= 500, t++, ants = select[ants, tau, 1/t]; 
     tau = (1 - Rho)*tau + Map[evaluatetau[#] &, ants];]
    Show[ListPointPlot3D[Map[Flatten, {#, evaluatetau[#]} & /@ ants], 
      PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
     Plot3D[-(x^4 + 3*y^4 - 0.2*Cos[3*Pi*x] - 0.4*Cos[4*Pi*y] + 
         0.6), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]]
```

[image]